# How to verify the transaction was completed?

Tags: transaction

Ideally I would like to watch some wallet address and get informed when new transaction has occured. In order to raise safety level I don't want to store mnemonic on the server.

I looked up node examples on official iota-sdk but couldn't find anything mentioned or I just don't understand the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate a `Client` object and ask it for [basicOutputIDs](https://wiki.iota.org/iota-sdk/references/nodejs/classes/Client/#basicoutputids) that are unlockable by your address. Once a new output appears there, some transaction that targets that address had been confirmed. In case you expect to also receive other objects like NFTs, you can also ask for either these output types or for generally any "outputID".

If you want to know the details of the transaction, you can load the output by output ID and find the amount and tokens, then load the transaction in case you are curious where you got that from.